# What's the missing number?

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

$\begin{array}{ccc}6&7&4\\
4&11&14\\
13&2&11\\
6&8&1\\
15&3&?\end{array}$

Own attempt at building a puzzle, 
find the missing number.

Comment: so, what's the solution?

Answer (score 1):

> I divided the table into three columns and summed up the cross sums of
>  their entries. This results in 26 for the first column and 22 for the
>  second one.
>  
>  [image: puzzle]
>  
>  The difference between those is 4, so maybe it should be 4 for the next difference, too. Thus, column three should have a cross sum sum of 18.
>  
>  **? = 6**

I think it's unlikely that this is really the solution, since you could make up several similar ways of "solving" the puzzle, but maybe it's worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the closest I get

> **13**

Reasoning

> if we sum the numbers in an **X Formation**, they turn out to be equal. Like: \begin{array}{cccccc}6&&7&&4\\& + &&& \\4&&11&&14\\&&& + &  \\13&&2&&11 & =28\\\\6&&8&&1\\\\15&&3&&?\end{array}-
>  \begin{array}{cccccc}&6&&7&&4\\&&&&+& \\&4&&11&&14\\&&+&&&\\28 =  &13&&2&&11\\\\&6&&8&&1\\\\&15&&3&&?\end{array} and if we use the same rule on the lower X formation like this
>  \begin{array}{cccccc}&6&&7&&4\\\\&4&&11&&14\\\\&13&&2&&11&\\&&&&+&\\&6&&8&&1\\&&+&&&\\34 =&15&&3&&?\end{array}-
>  \begin{array}{cccccc}6&&7&&4\\\\4&&11&&14\\\\13&&2&&11&\\&+&&&\\6&&8&&1\\&&&+&\\15&&3&&?& = 34 \end{array}
>  so "**?**" should be **13** to maintain this rule

Comment: Doesn't seem to hold in general: for the X in the center $4+2+1 \neq 6+2+14$

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware but this question didn't get any attempt so i think it's either too hard or too broad (the solution is not going to satisfy many). I still wanted to give it a try this way

Answer (score 0):

> 6+4+13+6=29
>
>  7+11+2+8=28
>
>  4+14+11+1=30
>
>  30-29=1
>
>  29-28=1
>
>  27-15=12
>
>  15-3=12
>
>  The answer is 27